# How to Select Project to run tvOS Version with NPM Start

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, tvos

If I set the simulator flag --simulator="Apple TV" with react-native run-ios, I get an error saying "Apple TV simulator was not found", I have checked the available list and it exists.

I think the problem is that npm is running the default IOS project and a TVos simulator was not found as an available IOS simulator not the tvOS project

I can build it with Xcode but then I cant use the live editing

Comment: I had the exact same issue and opened a pull request on the react-native github. It is an issue with the react-native ios code, where it ignores any apps that are not iOS. My fix also allows for tvOS apps. I've tested my changes and it fixes the issues. Hopefully it gets approved soon. You can follow the conversation here : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/17660